# JQuery Load More Posts On Click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add a "Show More" button at the bottom of my Blog page. The page is showing 12 posts by default. When I click on the "Show More" link I want more posts to be appended after the ones already on the page.

The "Show More" link is perfectly working using a bit of JQuery (see below). What it's not working is where the new posts are being rendered. I would like them to appear inside the  div and not inside a  inside the  div.

**This is the HTML:**

```
<div id="filter-results">
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>

 <a id="load-older-posts" href="/page/X/">Show More</a>
</div>
```

**This is the JQuery:**

```
$('#filter-results').on('click', '#load-older-posts', function(e) {
    // prevent new page load
    e.preventDefault();
    // store next page number
    var next_page = $(this).attr('href');
    // remove older posts button from DOM
    $(this).remove();
    // ajax older posts below existing posts
    $('#filter-results').append(
      $('<div />').load(next_page + ' #filter-results')
    );
  });
```

**With the current code what I get is:**

```
<div id="filter-results">
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div>
  <div id="filter-results">
   <div class="post"></div>
   <div class="post"></div>
   <div class="post"></div>
   <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <a id="load-older-posts" href="/page/X/">Show More</a>
</div>
```

**How do I get something like:**

```
<div id="filter-results">
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>

 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>
 <div class="post"></div>

 <a id="load-older-posts" href="/page/X/">Show More</a>
</div>
```

**TNX GUYS!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put append inside load function callback, also select `#filter-results`'s div child in load function.

```
$('<div>').load(next_page + ' #filter-results > div', function() {
    $('#filter-results').append($(this).html());
});
```

it's also possible to select using children's class

```
$('<div>').load(next_page + ' #filter-results > .post', function() {
    $('#filter-results').append($(this).html());
});
```

Or if you didn't want to select its child

```
$('<div>').load(next_page + ' #filter-results', function() {
    $('#filter-results').append($(this).find('#filter-results').html());
});
```

source : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-but-append-data-instead-of-replace#14737000001115765

Comment: Perfectly working...thanks so much for your help!!